# Perl "scalar" function returning "1" on an empty array

Tags: arrays, perl, scalar

The following Perl code will print a "1", however the function `test2` really has no legitimate input value.  Why does Perl act this way?

```
test();

sub test {
    my ($var) = @_;

    test2($var);
}

sub test2 {
    my (@array) = @_;
    print scalar @array;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test2($var)` passes one scalar to `test2` (`$var`), so one scalar is assigned to `@array` by `my (@array) = @_;`.

The value of the scalar in question (`$var`) is `undef`, since you assigned "nothing" to `$var` in `my ($var) = @_;`.

Maybe you want `test2(@_)` (passes the zero scalars in `@_`) instead of `test2($var)` (passes the one scalar `$var`)?

Comment: That's exactly what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: `test2( defined($var) ? $var : () )` aka `test2( $var // () )` may also be of interest.

Comment: Actually doing a little more digging I found this: `BEGIN { *test = \&test2 }` which makes the function `test` by definition the same as `test2` creating an alias to the function.  This is really the functionality I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `test`, `$var` is set to `undef` by the assignment. So your call to `test2` passes a list with one element, `undef`.